# Devise custom route not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I'm attempting to modify the Devise sessions controller to show a user's profile. The following is the modified sessions controller:

```
  class User::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_filter :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]
  respond_to :json

    # GET /resource/sign_in
    # def new
    #   super
    # end

    # POST /resource/sign_in
    # def create
    #   super
    # end

    # DELETE /resource/sign_out
    # def destroy
    #   super
    # end

    # protected

    # You can put the params you want to permit in the empty array.
    # def configure_sign_in_params
    #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :attribute
    # end


    def show
      respond_with User.find(params[:id])
    end

  end
```

And the following is my response when attempting to hit the show method with a json request:

```
Started GET "/users/1.json" for ::1 at 2015-10-25 22:47:34 -0400

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for Devise::SessionsController):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:132:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/unknown_action.html.erb within rescues/layout (0.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (26.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (57.5ms)
```

But my routes show the route exists:

```
                    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                      root GET    /                              application#angular
          new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
              user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
      destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
             user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
         new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
        edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                           PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                           PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
  cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
         user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
     new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
    edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                           PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                           PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                           DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                           GET    /users/:id(.:format)           devise/sessions#show
```

This is my routes.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

      root to: 'application#angular'
      devise_for :users, :controllers => {:session => "sessions"}

      devise_scope :user do
      get '/users/:id' => 'devise/sessions#show'
      end


    end
```

Any ideas what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually create a separate resource for users.

try this command:

`rails generate controller users`

Then add your show method on users controller.

Your route should look like:

`devise_for :users
resources :users`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
root to: 'application#angular'
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "users/sessions"}
```

`"users/sessions"` will make `devise` use your `User::SessionsController` instead of its default `SessionsController`

**Edit1**

the filesystem structure shall be like
`app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb`

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  #use custom layout for devise
  layout "login"

end
```

the `users` dir keeps all the devise resources controllers separate. (say if you have multiple devise resources like `users`, `admin`). There will be `admin` directory if you need to define `admin` resource.

Comment: Trying this I get `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Users):` stack error. Any ideas ? thanks